# Peculiar android RuntimeException

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I just received the wierdest looking stack trace on my Developer Console. What puzzles me is where "MArcos" came from? This was the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=genius.mohammad.accelerometer.mouse

Try recreating the exception if you want and explain to me what it is if you can. Thanks!

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{genius.mohammad.accelerometer.mouse/genius.mohammad.accelerometermouse.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'MArcos' as integer
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'MArcos' as integer
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:383)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:372)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
at genius.mohammad.accelerometermouse.MainActivity.updatePrefs(MainActivity.java:85)
at genius.mohammad.accelerometermouse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

... 11 more

Comment: Are you using pro guard? If so that might explain why you aren't familiar with the variable `MArcos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'MArcos' as integer
```

It seems in your code (`MainActivity.java: line number 85`) you are trying to parse String as Integer.

Comment: Oh wow i didnt even read to that point before posting this. Thanks ill take a look!